# 4 column Repeater control duplicating data

Tags: html, asp.net, repeater

The requirement is to use a Repeater. So I created a Repeater with 4 columns inside the ItemTemplate. When the datasource is bound to the repeater, on each row the same data appears in each column. I am confused as to why this is happening and how to correct it. At the moment, I do not have a Repeater_ItemDataBound event setup. How do I make each  in the ItemTemplate to display another record.

The following is the HTML for the repeater:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptSectionManufacturers" runat="server" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="divManufacturerRule">
            <hr />
            </div>
            <table style="width: 100%; margin:10px;">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:25%; text-align:left;">
                    <a href='products/a-<%# ((string)Eval("name")).RemoveSpecialCharacters(string.Empty) %>-manufacturer-<%# Eval("attributeid") %>/'><%# Eval("name") %></a>
                </td>
                <td style="width:25%; text-align:left;">
                    <a href='products/a-<%# ((string)Eval("name")).RemoveSpecialCharacters(string.Empty) %>-manufacturer-<%# Eval("attributeid") %>/'><%# Eval("name") %></a>
                </td>
                <td style="width:25%; text-align:left;">
                    <a href='products/a-<%# ((string)Eval("name")).RemoveSpecialCharacters(string.Empty) %>-manufacturer-<%# Eval("attributeid") %>/'><%# Eval("name") %></a>
                </td>
                <td style="width:25%; text-align:left;">
                    <a href='products/a-<%# ((string)Eval("name")).RemoveSpecialCharacters(string.Empty) %>-manufacturer-<%# Eval("attributeid") %>/'><%# Eval("name") %></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

[image: Example of Repeater output]
Here is the output of the repeater

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Separator template?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aribeiro/archive/2005/01/12/351439.aspx

The example seems similar to what you're trying to do.